# join string with separate start/end characters

Tags: java, string, join, guava

What's a nice way to join strings with different start/ending characters depending on if there's one or more matches?

Expected output

```
[1] foo=bar
[2] foo=(bar & baz & quz)
```

I'm looking to see if there's something a tad more elegant than my solution

```
String s = Joiner.on(" & ").join(elements);
return elements.size() > 1 ? "(".concat(s).concat(")") : s;
```

Comment: The code would look better if you used the `+` operator for String concatenation: `return elements.size() > 1 ? "(" + s + ")" : s;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a nicer way.  Joiner (somewhat deliberately) only does straightforward joining.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly more elegant, but for anyone who wants to avoid Guava and go with java 8 Streams:

```
   public class App {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bar","baz","quz"));
            List<String> stringListSingle = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bar"));

            System.out.println(printStrings(stringList));
            System.out.println(printStrings(stringListSingle));
        }

        private static String printStrings(List<String> stringList) {
            return stringList.size() == 1 ?  String.join(" & ", stringList) : stringList.stream()
                                                                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ","{", "}"));
        }

    }
```